# How to setup both express and standard table rates for delivery

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.7 and i am puzzled to how i can implement both delivery options Express and Standard delivery options when both are not related to usps/usp please help me this is following rates i want to configure

```
1.UK Delivery Orders
1.    Standard Deliveries Orders Over £50 Free
2.    Express Deliveries Orders Over £50 Plus £6.95*
3.    Standard Delivery Orders Under £50 £5.30
4.    Express Deliveries Orders Under £50 Plus £6.95*
2. EU Deliveries
1.    Orders Over € 60 Free
2.    Orders Under € 60 € 14.00
3. Rest of Europe Deliveries
1.    All Orders £8.00
4. Rest of World
1.    All Orders £15.00

* Order by 12pm today for delivery before 1.00pm tomorrow (Weekends and Bank Holidays excluded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom delivery option the best solution is to use Owebia SHipping 2.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html

My store has 85 shipping methods enabled thanks to this helpful module.

Regards :

Comment: how this payment method works can you please help me to understand thiss extension i just install this extension and enable first default shipping then tring to complete checkout process but when i fill address information keep selected radio field ship to this address but notthing happend i am still on this same step unable to continue on next step

Answer (score 2):

I think that Webshoppapps module is a better option and it's free. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html

The issue is out of the box Magento doesn't have the option to have multiple shipping rates available for one situation. This gets round this easily.

I created a CSV for you to use with Matrix Rates:

```
Country Region/State    City    Zip/Postal Code From    Zip/Postal Code To  Order Subtotal From Order Subtotal To   Shipping Price  Delivery Type
GBR *               0   50  5.3 Standard Delivery
GBR *               50  99999   0   Standard Delivery
GBR *               0   50  6.95    Express Delivery
GBR *               50  99999   6.95    Express Delivery
AUT *               0   60  14  European Shipping
BEL *               0   60  14  European Shipping
BGR *               0   60  14  European Shipping
CYP *               0   60  14  European Shipping
CZE *               0   60  14  European Shipping
DEU *               0   60  14  European Shipping
DNK *               0   60  14  European Shipping
ESP *               0   60  14  European Shipping
EST *               0   60  14  European Shipping
FIN *               0   60  14  European Shipping
FRA *               0   60  14  European Shipping
GRC *               0   60  14  European Shipping
HUN *               0   60  14  European Shipping
IRL *               0   60  14  European Shipping
ITA *               0   60  14  European Shipping
LTU *               0   60  14  European Shipping
LUX *               0   60  14  European Shipping
LVA *               0   60  14  European Shipping
MLT *               0   60  14  European Shipping
NLD *               0   60  14  European Shipping
POL *               0   60  14  European Shipping
PRT *               0   60  14  European Shipping
ROU *               0   60  14  European Shipping
SVK *               0   60  14  European Shipping
SVN *               0   60  14  European Shipping
SWE *               0   60  14  European Shipping
AUT *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
BEL *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
BGR *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
CYP *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
CZE *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
DEU *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
DNK *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
ESP *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
EST *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
FIN *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
FRA *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
GRC *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
HUN *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
IRL *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
ITA *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
LTU *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
LUX *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
LVA *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
MLT *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
NLD *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
POL *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
PRT *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
ROU *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
SVK *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
SVN *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
SWE *               60  99999   0   European Shipping
ABW *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AFG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AGO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AIA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ALA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ALB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AND *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ANT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ARE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ARG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ARM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ASM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ATA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ATF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ATG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AUS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
AZE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BDI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BEN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BFA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BGD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BHR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BHS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BIH *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BLM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BLR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BLZ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BMU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BOL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BRA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BRB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BRN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BTN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BVT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
BWA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CAF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CAN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CCK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CHE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CHL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CHN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CIV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CMR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
COD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
COG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
COK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
COL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
COM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CPV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CRI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CUB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CXR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
CYM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
DJI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
DMA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
DOM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
DZA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ECU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
EGY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ERI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ESH *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ETH *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
FJI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
FLK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
FRO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
FSM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GAB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GEO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GGY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GHA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GIB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GIN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GLP *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GMB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GNB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GNQ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GRD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GRL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GTM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GUF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GUM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
GUY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
HKG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
HMD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
HND *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
HRV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
HTI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IDN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IMN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IND *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IOT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IRN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
IRQ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ISL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ISR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
JAM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
JEY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
JOR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
JPN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KAZ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KEN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KGZ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KHM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KIR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KNA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KOR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
KWT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LAO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LBN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LBR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LBY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LCA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LIE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LKA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
LSO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MAC *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MAF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MAR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MCO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MDA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MDG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MDV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MEX *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MHL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MKD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MLI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MMR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MNE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MNG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MNP *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MOZ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MRT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MSR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MTQ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MUS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MWI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MYS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
MYT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NAM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NCL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NER *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NFK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NGA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NIC *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NIU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NOR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NPL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NRU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
NZL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
OMN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PAK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PAN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PCN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PER *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PHL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PLW *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PNG *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PRI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PRK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PRY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PSE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
PYF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
QAT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
REU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
RUS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
RWA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SAU *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SDN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SEN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SGP *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SGS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SHN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SJM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SLB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SLE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SLV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SMR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SOM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SPM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SRB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
STP *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SUR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SWZ *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SYC *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
SYR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TCA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TCD *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TGO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
THA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TJK *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TKL *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TKM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TLS *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TON *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TTO *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TUN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TUR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TUV *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TWN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
TZA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
UGA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
UKR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
UMI *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
URY *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
USA *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
UZB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VAT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VCT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VEN *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VGB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VIR *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VNM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
VUT *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
WLF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
WSM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
YEM *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ZAF *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ZMB *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
ZWE *               0   99999   15  Worldwide Delivery
```

Let me know if you need anymore help?

Comment: The only thing to consider here is I haven't made a distinction between EU and Rest of Europe. You could do that yourself. Here's a link to Magento Country codes if you need help: =(=http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/11/magento-shipping-country-codes/

Comment: no its not visible in magento when i install in magento i have also check shipping method section but there is no option for multiple table rates